# dotnet 5: Decimal silently truncated - how to make it break?

Tags: .net, .net-core, decimal

The following is done with .Net 5:

The following line is not allowed by the compiler as the number exceeds the maximum long value:

```
long value = 123456789123456789123456789123456789; // <= Not allowed by compiler
```

However, the following line is allowed by both the compiler and by the runtime:

```
Decimal value = 123456789123456789.123456789123456789m; // No compile time error, no runtime error.
```

The issue is, that the value is immediately truncated into 123456789123456789,12345678912. So the value is actually altered without any notice.

I would like to know if dotnet can be set up to blow up in this case as I want things to break early, at compile time at best or at least at runtime.

Anyone one out there who solved this?

Comment: I guess decimal works similar to double, where this would also not cause an error.

Comment: But to my knowledge, Decimal is not actually working like a double, as it does not use floating point arithmetic?

Comment: True, but if you remove the "." from the decimal constant, it causes an error, just because decimal has a fixed number of digits for the whole part. The point is that there is no warning/error when the value is truncated due to lack of accuracy, but an error is reported if the significant part is too big.

Comment: @StephanMøller it also isn't arbitrary precision, though; it has to round somewhere, as it has fixed size

Comment: You are correct that it is different to `double` but `Decimal` still only has a set precision based on a 96 bit number

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types) tell you that the precision is limited to 28-29 digits.

Comment: You can use `BigInteger` or `Rational` if you need a precision beyond the range of double or decimal.

Comment: Loss of accuracy is not an overflow, so not sure which error you think it should throw

Comment: @PMF and Marc: I agree that it cannot represent an infinite number of values with a finite number of bits. What I am seeking is to get a runtime error when the rounding happens.

Comment: @PMF: Thanks for pointing out other types - nice to know. Right now I am hunting a  "break early" solution.

Comment: @Charlieface: Any exception type would be fine with me.

Comment: @StephanMøller: No, `System.Decimal` is still a floating point type. But it's a *decimal* point rather than a *binary* point. As Charlieface says, basically you'll need a Roslyn analyzer. (Or a mixture of code review and tests to catch this - is it biting you often?)

Comment: @Jon Thanks for the answer. No its not biting me often. I just build everything to break early and I dont like the fact that when I deserialize "11111111111111111111.222222222222222" from json to a decimal, it works. I would like to break in this case. I already break when trying to deserialize a double value as this has much more problems to it. I will dig into the newtonsoft-part of the code to check if I can catch this explicitly by myself.

Comment: Hold it: you started by talking about literals in *code* now you're talking about Newtonsoft deserializer? What is your actual use-case?

Comment: Charlieface: I would like to know whenever rounding happens as this is critical. My actual cases is during deserialization so I may be able to cover this case down the newtonsoft path. But a more general approach was to let decimal itself blow when rounding happens. So that's why I mentioned newtonsoft :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is by design.**

[From the C# specification:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#real-literals)

> A real literal suffixed by `M` or `m` is of type `decimal`. For example, the literals `1m`, `1.5m`, `1e10m`, and `123.456M` are all of type `decimal`. This literal is converted to a `decimal` value by taking the exact value, and, if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value using banker's rounding. Any scale apparent in the literal is preserved unless the value is rounded or the value is zero (in which latter case the sign and scale will be `0`). Hence, the literal `2.900m` will be parsed to form the decimal with sign `0`, coefficient `2900`, and scale `3`.

I'm afraid your only option would be to build a Code Analyzer that would mark an error on such a line.